# Create linked server in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I tried to create linked server following the syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM Server.Database.Schema.Table
```

My created syntax:

```
 SELECT * FROM 145.17.58.228.AHS_System.AHS_User
```

But getting error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '145.17'.

How can I make a linked sever?

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a linked server just because you are using `select * from server`

The official Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine) shows you how to create a linked server. If you are having difficulty with this, please edit your question with a specific problem.

See also: [How to Add a Linked Server](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/how-to-add-a-linked-server)

---

<sub>*[Community Wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) created from comments left on the question:*</sub>